# Qtp and vbscript: ArrayList of Arraylists with Arrays inside (and outside) a function

Tags: vbscript, arraylist, qtp

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one. First, I'm not able to add the correct ArrayLists to the ArrayList; it keeps adding the last ArrayList in the iteration and overwriting the previous one(s).

This is how it's supposed to be:

ArrayList testCaseList: ArrayList containing multiple tTestCase ArrayLists
ArrayList tTestCase: ArrayList containing multiple tempArray Arrays
Array tempArray: Array containing two string entries (read from an Excel file)

Here's the relevant code:

```
'The ArrayList with ArrayLists (test cases):
Dim testCaseList : Set testCaseList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
'Temporary ArrayList containing test cases:
Dim tTestCase : Set tTestCase = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")

Set my_sheet = ExcelObject.sheets.item(testCaseSheet)

'Function that reads the test cases from the Excel file:
Function getTestsCaseActions (row, col)
    Do While my_sheet.cells(row, 2).Value <> ""
        'The first array to add to tTestCase:
        tempArray = array(my_sheet.cells(row, 2), my_sheet.cells(row, 3))
        tTestCase.Add tempArray

        'Go through the rows and columns and get the rest of the arrays to add:
        Do While my_sheet.cells(row, col).Value <> ""
            tTestCase.Add array(my_sheet.cells(row, col), my_sheet.cells(row+1, col))
            col = col+1
        Loop
        'We now have a tTestCase ArrayList complete with the test case arrays.

        'Test print the arrays in the tTestCase Arraylist:
        'Dim i
        'For i=0 To tTestCase.Count-1
        '    MsgBox tTestCase(i)(0) & " -> " & tTestCase(i)(1)  'Works fine.
        'Next

        'Add the tTestCase ArrayList to the testCastList ArrayList:
        testCaseList.Add tTestCase

        'Test:
        MsgBox testCaseList.count     'This LOOKS right - the count increases for each iteration
        Dim y
        For y=0 To testCaseList.Count-1
            MsgBox "Added to testCaseList: " & testCaseList(y)(0)(0)
        Next
        'But no. This is how the printout looks for each iteration:
        'Iteration 0: TC01
        'Iteration 1: TC02
        '             TC02
        'Iteration 2: TC03
                      TC03
        '             TC03

        tTestCase.Clear

        row = row+2
        col = 4
    Loop
End Function

getTestsCaseActions 3, 4

'MsgBox testCaseList.Count        'This shows 3, which appears correct...
'MsgBoc testCaseList(0).Count     'But this shows zero...? Should be 5...
```

As I mention in the code comments, testing the tTestCase ArrayList for each iteration shows that the data is read and stored into it correctly.

But when I add the tTestCase ArrayList to the testCaseList ArrayList, it does not work. In the first iteration, it adds the first tTestCase once. So far, so good. Then in the second iteration, it adds the second tTestCase twice, apparently overwriting the first one. Then it's the same in the third iteration: It adds the third tTestCase three times, apparently overwriting the existing ones.

In addition to this, if I try to access testCaseList OUTSIDE of the function - or even IN the function but outside the loop, the count shows 3 (which is the number of tTestCases created from the Excel file), but their count again is 0. So, there's nothing there but empty arraylists. This I don't understand, since the ArrayLists are initiated outside of the function?

Obviously, there is something related to writing and storing in ArrayLists that I don't understand here. But I've been unable to find much relevant info about this - is ArrayList not widely used in vbscript? (Perhaps since it's a .NET object?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sure way to problems with ArrayLists is to forget that ArrayLists are objects that are assigned as references. Putting alA into alB and then modifying/clearing alA will show in alB, because alB contains references to (not copies of) alA. Demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim alA : Set alA = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
alA.Add "one"
alA.Add "two"
Dim alB : Set alB = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
alB.Add alA
alB.Add alA

Dim e
For Each e In alB
    WScript.Echo 0, e(0), e(1)
Next

WScript.Echo "----------"

WScript.Echo "alA(0)    = ""eins"""
alA(0)    = "eins"
WScript.Echo "alB(1)(1) = ""zwei"""
alB(1)(1) = "zwei"

For Each e In alB
    WScript.Echo 1, e(0), e(1)
Next
WScript.Echo 2, "alA(1)", alA(1)

WScript.Echo "----------"

alA.Clear
WScript.Echo "After alA.Clear"

For Each e In alB
    WScript.Echo 3, e.Count
Next

WScript.Echo "----------"

WScript.Echo "alA Is alB(0)", CStr(alA Is alB(0))
WScript.Echo "alA Is alB(1)", CStr(alA Is alB(1))
```

output:

```
cscript 2-19941052.vbs
0 one two
0 one two
----------
alA(0)    = "eins"
alB(1)(1) = "zwei"
1 eins zwei
1 eins zwei
2 alA(1) zwei
----------
After alA.Clear
3 0
3 0
----------
alA Is alB(0) True
alA Is alB(1) True
```

**Update wrt comment:**

That's easy to check, use

```
alB.Add alA.Clone()
alB.Add alA.Clone()
```

and

```
For Each e In alB
    WScript.Echo 3, e.Count, e(0), e(1)
Next
```

and you'll get:

```
cscript 3-19941052.vbs
0 one two
0 one two
----------
alA(0)    = "eins"
alB(1)(1) = "zwei"
1 one two
1 one zwei
2 alA(1) two
----------
After alA.Clear
3 2 one two
3 2 one zwei
----------
alA Is alB(0) False
alA Is alB(1) False
```

You have mentioned the caveat yourself: There still be dragons, if your Sub-ArrayLists contain references/objects.

Comment: Ah, ok - I understand. Is there any way around this, do you think? I'm not sure how I can fill the ArrayList with other ArrayList without creating temporary arraylists.

Comment: Hm. It seems that doing "testCaseList.Add tTestCase.Clone()" will add a new (shallow) copy of tTestCase, instead of a reference...?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the trick is to use the Clone() function of ArrayList. This creates a (shallow) copy of the ArrayList which can be inserted into the other ArrayList, instead of just creating a reference.

```
testCaseList.Add tTestCase.Clone()
```